# Remove edit button from UITableView?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

is it possible to remove or hide the edit button completely on the UITableView?

Basically, it's an information app, and I don't want users to accidentally delete cells :(

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[self.tableView setEditing:NO];
```

Comment: How to set that property via storyboard?